# How to init firebase in the right directory?

Tags: firebase, terminal, polymer

```
SEB:~ SEB$ cd /Users/SEB/Desktop/demo/polymer
SEB:polymer SEB$ firebase init



You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

/Users/SEB
```

Just dont understand why... How can i init Firebase in my "polymer" directory ? Thank you. Sébastien

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Check `/Users/SEB` for a `firebase.json` file and delete it if it exists. When `firebase init` runs it goes up the directory tree looking for a parent directory that's already initialized as a Firebase project.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Comment: Thanks ..I didn't know why my folder was empty after running firebase init